# Bike identification

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I am trying to identify this bike.

It has a club cutout in lugs and 4 card suits on inside of fork crown.  Frame's serial number is 75390.

Also has direct frame mount above rim mafac Brake bosses. Takes a 27.2mm seat post.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Needs more pictures.  At least one of the full frame.

Answer (score 5):

The frame looks like a Mercian Strada Speciale based on the clover leaf cut outs in the lugs.

[image]
[LFGSS.com 1985 Mercian Strada Speciale](https://www.lfgss.com/conversations/254068/)

At the [Mercian website there is a collection of catalogs](http://www.merciancycles.co.uk/about-us/history/) you can use to compare your bike to the manufacturer's specifications

The fork is confusing. I can't find a Mercian with a fork crown **EDIT: tang - the inside of the fork crown with the spade, club, heart and diamond** - like yours.
Usually a manufacturer will make the frame and fork the same for a specific model of bike for a whole year or several years if the economics are working for that model. I couldn't find a year, catalog, that has that fork on that model.
Maybe the fork is from a different bike?

As JoeK below says bicycle lug makers back in the day made these parts for frame and fork makers to use. The long tang on the inside of the fork is actually a sperate part, not attached to the crown, that is brazed or silver soldered on to the fork.

[image]
[bikeretrogrouch.com](http://bikeretrogrouch.blogspot.com/2013/12/lovely-fork-crowns.html)

I did find a Serotta fork crown that was similar:
[image]
Though the [fork crown pictured has the spade, club, heart and diamond](http://www.classicrendezvous.com/USA/Serotta/Serotta_1982_catalog.htm) but it also has a stylized "S" on the top of the crown.

This [Saba Equipe frame](https://www.vintagevelo.co.uk/shop/frames/saba-equipe-frame/) has the cutouts,
but has their brand logo on the top of the crown
[image]

Comment: I agree frame is definitely a Mercian.

Comment: Mercian may have used that fork crown, you could ask. These parts are ordered from a lug casting company and don't have to be unique to a brand.

Comment: My 1983 Mercian Olympic has a square fork crown like OP's, but mine is scooped differently along the sides. Based on serial number, I think OP's frame is from 1990.

Comment: Mercian serial numbers are usually XXXYY where YY are the last 2 digits of the year. http://www.classicrendezvous.com/British_isles/Mercian/Mercian_main.htm and http://bikeretrogrouch.blogspot.com/2014/02/mercian-cycles-history-and-tradition.html . OP's is XXX90, so 1990.

Comment: The Mercian site has a 1991 catalog with a Strada Speciale showing the cutouts. See catalog page here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLUwS.jpg and detail of lugs (which look like OP's) here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjMZi.jpg

Comment: @JoeK Mercian lugs, at least on their higher-end frames, are hand-cut.

Answer (score 1):

More photos might be helpful, but the club motif is strongly identified with Colnago. Apparently Colnago was pretty spotty about serial numbers for a long time. [Here's some info](https://www.bikeforums.net/classic-vintage/830017-colnago-super-timeline-corrections-additions.html)

Comment: Definitely not the colnago clover

Answer (score 0):

It might be a martelly bike. That someone wanted as a cyclocross bike. Or someone that made
a benotto frame Into a martelly. Ive seen it done with those chunky seat stays. And I even own 2 fake colnagos that are lighter and stronger than the stock 5lb 11oz frame. But look the part to every detail. They made one that was a colnago sport and another was a martelly. But now 2 supers to every detail.

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles.  Can you add some pictures or links to the specific bikes and models you're talking about?  This seems very general, and isn't really making a solid identification.

Answer (score -2):

Downtube shifter bosses suggest an 80s bike, or an earlier 90s frame.

The handlebars are untaped and what I can see looks like galvinised steel, which leans toward 80s.

All I can say is a lugged steel frame from the 80s.   Please add a full photo from the bike's right-hand side.

---

Aside - your shiny new brake pads are for Alloy rims - are your rims aluminium or steel ?